# Best way to sort an NSArray of NSDictionary objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm struggling with trying to sort an array of dictionaries.

My dictionaries have a couple of values of interest, price, popularity etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Use `NSSortDescriptor` like this..

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"interest" ascending:YES];
stories = [stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
recent = [stories copy];
```

`stories` is the array you want to sort. `recent` is another mutable array which has sorted dictionary values. Change the `@"interest"` with the key value on which you have to sort.

All the best

Comment: This is good, but it does leak. 1) the sort descriptor should be released or autoreleased, and 2) The copy call is not needed the line can be deleted.

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"interest"  ascending:YES] autorelease];
    [stories sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

Comment: You can use
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"interest" ascending:YES];

Comment: recent = [[stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]] copy];

Comment: You need to store the output during the sort call: NSArray* recent = [stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

Comment: Can I use "@allkey" type value in init of sortDescriptor ?

Comment: if stories is a mutable array, you can use [stories sortUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]]; instead

Answer (score 25):

```
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"YOUR-KEY" ascending:YES], nil]];
```

I don't really want to break it into multiple lines. It's already simple enough for me.

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"  ascending:YES];
    [resultArray1 sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

Answer (score 11):

You can just traverse from the parent to the required child property. For e.g.

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"parent.child.child"  ascending:YES];
```

Comment: You little star. this helped me sort a sub sub dictionary. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It doesn't answer the question!

Answer (score 4):

Update , sortUsingDescriptors is now sortedArrayUsingDescriptors

So, its like:

```
items  = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing - `[NSArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors]` and - `[NSMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors]`. The latest still exists and hasn't been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Write a sort function that compares the relevant fields in two dictionaries. When you have this version you can for example use `NSArray#sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` to sort your array.

See [NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCHBAHB)

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"YOUR-KEY" ascending:YES], nil]];
```

Remember assign to array