# Sort of an array from plist file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, plist

I have a custom plist file which contains dictionaries. Each dictionary contains information about one car:

```
     <key>Ford</key>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Ford</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>green</string>
    <key>price</key>
    <integer>45000</integer>
</dict

    <key>Toyota</key>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Toyota</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>blue</string>
    <key>price</key>
    <integer>40000</integer>
</dict

    <key>BMW</key>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>BMW</string>
    <key>color</key>
    <string>blue</string>
    <key>price</key>
    <integer>40000</integer>
</dict>
```

I also have an UITableView and I fill it with some cars from this plist.

```
 NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dictionary objectEnumerator];
    id returnValue;


    while ((returnValue = [enumerator nextObject])) 
    {

        if ([[returnValue valueForKey:@"color"]isEqualToString:@"blue")
        {  
            [array addObject:[returnValue valueForKey:@"name"]];
        }
```

**Question:** When I get an UITableView with some cars in it, how can I sort them by price now? For example, BMW is cheaper than Ford, so it should be in the first cell and Ford must be in a second cell. I know that Apple has already created easy ways to sort arrays but how can I use it here ? Thanks !
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2393745/251513):

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price"  ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks ! But my app crashes:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x894c850> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key price.'`

Comment: nice and easy and extra helpful bro. + 1

Answer (score 0):

First extract the values of price into a list.Then Use NSSorDescriptor.

```
{
   NSArray *carArray=[[NSArray alloc] initwithContentsofFile:@"youFileName"    ofType:@"plist"];
   NSmutableArray *priceList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for(int index=0;index<[carArray count];index++)
   {
      NSDictionary *valueList=[carArray objectAtIndex:index];
      [priceList addObject:[valueList objectForKey:@"Price"]];

   }
   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price"  ascending:YES];
   [priceList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Now You will get the sorted array based on Price.
    }