# change object in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, object, replace, nsmutablearray

i have a NSMutableArray. 
In this is the structure of my Array:

```
{
Distance = 0;
Name = Name1;
Town = Town1;
}
{
Distance = 0;
Name = Name2;
Town = Town2;
}
```

And now I want to replace "Distance". For example that "Distance = 15".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's say your initial `NSMutableArray` is called **initial** (given that it contains `NSMutableDictionary` objects...

To alter the first element's `distance` value :

```
[[initial objectAtIndex:0] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15] 
                           forKey:@"Distance"];
```

---

**IF** you want to perform the correction for **every** entry in the array, just do it this way :

```
for (NSMutableDictionary* entry in initial)
{
     [entry setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15] 
              forKey:@"Distance"];
}
```

Comment: 2013-02-13 08:54:42.591 Heurigen-App[555:11c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1848012 0x1178e7e 0x1847deb 0x180e347 0xb919bf 0x6226 0x17af4b 0x17b01f 0x16380b 0x17419b 0x11092d 0x118c6b0 0x2fbefc0 0x2fb333c 0x2fb3150 0x2f310bc 0x2f32227 0x2f328e2 0x1810afe 0x1810a3d 0x17ee7c2 0x17edf44 0x17ede1b 0x17a27e3 0x17a2668 0xc065c 0x26bd 0x25e5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: @theandrew The error message is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it? As I've already mentioned, the array has to contain instances of `NSMutableDictionary`. If they're just `NSDictionary` instances (= IMmutable), how could they be altered?

Comment: @theandrew Could you post the code with which you create your initial array?

Comment: news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

Comment: @theandrew Try this : `news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];`. It should work.

Comment: perfect it works!! Can you also help me how i can insert a String to Distance?

Comment: @theandrew To distance??? Distance is supposed to be an `NSNumber` value, nope? However, if you mean adding **another** key/value pair for some entry, just do it as before. E.g. `[entry setValue:yourString forKey:yourKeyName];`

Comment: @theandrew Glad to have helped, mate! ;-)

Comment: I have another question: how can i sort my array after distance?

Comment: @theandrew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects