# Sorting negative and positive numbers in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am listing out a quantity percentage like stuff for an item via a webservice.The response that I get is an array of dictionaries similar to the below code.I need it in a sorted format

```
NSArray *numberArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-12.0], @"price", nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-86.0],@"price", nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-8.0],@"price", nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.0],@"price", nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0],@"price", nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:112.0],@"price", nil], nil];
```

Here's the log of the JSON response

```
[
    {
        price = "-12";
    },
        {
        price = "-86";
    },
        {
        price = "-8";
    },
        {
        price = 12;
    },
        {
        price = 2;
    },
        {
        price = 112;
    }
]
```

Comment: You are mixing string and int?

Comment: it's JSON, I think the standard says the quotes can be avoided in case of plain numbers.

Comment: Looks like negative numbers are  automatically converted in string format.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella But why would a JSON writer sometimes quotes and sometimes not?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects

Comment: You are right, but I'm afraid that's the effect of `NSLog`.

Comment: No , the output is like (
        {
        price = "-12";
    },
        {
        price = "-86";
    },
        {
        price = "-8";
    },
        {
        price = 12;
    },
        {
        price = 2;
    },
        {
        price = 112;
    }
)

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks,actually it worked,i made an error with the sort key at first

Answer (score 4):

```
NSArray *sortedResult = [numberArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *num1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"price"];
    NSNumber *num2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"price"];
    return [num1 compare:num2];
}];
NSLog(@"---%@",sortedResult);
```

If you want the sortedResult in descending order then interchange the num1 and num2 in
    return statement.

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey:` to access elements of a dictionary.

Comment: You can also take advantage of modern Objective-C syntax and achieve something like: `{ return [obj1[@"price"] compare:obj2[@"price"]]; }`

Answer (score 2):

If the prices are stored as `NSNumber` objects, then the method from @trojanfoe's link ([Best way to sort an NSArray of NSDictionary objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects)) should work:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [numberArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
```

But from your last comment it seems that the prices are stored as *strings*.
In that case the following works, because `floatValue` converts each string to a
floating point value:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price.floatValue" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [numberArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
```

Comment: Looks like it could be a mix of `NSNumber` and `NSString` objects if that JSON is to be believed.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Actually negative NSNumbers inside a dictionary are NSLogged as "-12" with quotation marks, so it is impossible to see from the NSLog output whether that are numbers or strings. - But OP has now confirmed that your link helped.

Comment: @MartinR I believe using `price.floatValue` wouldn't harm even in case of `NSNumbers`.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: That is correct. But if I interpret the output of the [Objective-C message tracing](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/) correctly, the floating point numbers are converted back to NSNumber for the comparison, so that would be less effective.

Comment: Definitely not the way to go if you know the input type a priori. In case you don't (strings or numbers), it would provide a general solution

Answer (score 1):

You are not sorting numbers. You are sorting dictionaries, according to a common "price" element:

```
sortedArray = [numberArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
    return [a[@"price"] compare:b[@"price"]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sortedArray = [numberArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    float first  = [(NSNumber *)a[@"price"] floatValue];
    float second = [(NSNumber *)b[@"price"] floatValue];

    if (first > second) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (first < second) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```