# NSSortDiscriptor sort positive values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

In my core data, I'm asking for x amount of objects sorting by distance (NSNumber[double]) in ascending order.
The problem is it gives me back also negative numbers.
I know it make sense but I want only positive numbers, how can I do it?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = generateManagedObjectContext();

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kCORE_DATA_ALL_TRAPS_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Specify how the fetched objects should be sorted
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];

    // Limit the restlus to specific number
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:numberOfTraps];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil || fetchedObjects.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"%s error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
        return nil;
    }
```

Comment: sortDescriptor only sorts values, you'll need to filter or fetch only positive values.

Comment: I think you need to use `NSPredicate`

Comment: How can a *distance* be negative ?

Comment: @MartinR that's right, need to check it out.

Comment: @IdanMoshe can u checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510167/sorting-negative-and-positive-numbers-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"distance >= %d", 0];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did but I have an error: "-[_NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Comment: @IdanMoshe what is the type of `distance`?

Comment: distance is kind of double.

Comment: I think that field is a `string`, so try using `predicateWithFormat:@"distance.doubleValue >= %d"` or `@"distance.intValue >= %d"`

Comment: It's NSNumber, that fixed my problem. :)

Comment: If using Predicate that way is not always straightforward, use block-based predicate instead.

Answer (score 1):

As most comments mentioned, you only used NSSortDescriptor while you can also use NSPredicate to do the job.

You can find an example in Apple Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetching.html). There's a section dedicated to using both.