# Remove last digit when it's a 0 in double (or any other option) when comparing

Tags: ios, objective-c, predicate

I'm adding a bunch of coordinates into quad tree and when I'm asking for the closest coordinate near my location, sometimes I've coordinate with 0 at the end, added automatically perhaps by the quad tree or I don't know how.
The problem is when I'm asking the double value in my core data using predicate it won't match because of the 0 digit addition to the number.

I thought about removing it when I've 0 but I'm sure there is a better way doing it.

For example:

- Near location 31.123456, 34.123456, the nearest is 31.123444, 34.123450
  when '34.123450' is actually 34.12345 in the database.

Comment: is your values saved as NSString in the database ?

Comment: As @Basheer_CAD says, why store numbers using a string?  If you are concerned about floating point comparison issues, then consider *encoding* the values into an integer (int = float * 1000, given the range is +/- 180.0)?

Comment: Honestly, you should at least understand the differences between a number represented as a string, a number represented by `NSNumber` and a number as a C primitive (e.g. double).

Comment: Also the discussion following http://stackoverflow.com/a/21875197/1187415 strongly indicates that the coordinates are stored as strings, even if you claim that they are stored as numbers.

Comment: NSNumber (double), in qiad tree they are double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Convert float to String

```
NSString *str_lat = @"34.123450";


NSString *trimmedString=[str_lat substringFromIndex:MAX((int)[str_lat length]-1, 0)];

if([trimmedString isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    str_lat = [str_lat substringToIndex:[str_lat length] - 1];
}
else
{

}
NSLog(@"%@",str_lat);
```

Answer (score 1):

First: You should not store numbers as strings. 7.3 and 7.30 *are* the same values with simply different representations. You should not compare the representations, but the value.

Second: You should not compare floating-point numbers with == but their difference to a delta. In a calculation precision might get lost, rounding is applied and so on. The "mathematical" equal values might be physical different by a more or less small amount.

Comment: The result from quad tree can be 7.30, then i'm asking in predicate if it is exist in core data, then it tells me it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you store your data as *numbers* there is no representation of 7.3 as "7.3" or "7.30" or "7.300". (To be honest, there is an internal representation probably according to IEEE somewhat.) Therefore you have to compare the number 7.3 (*not* the string "7.3") to the number 7.3 (*not* to the string "7.30"). 7.3 *is* 7.3 indepenendly of its representation, even it is represented with 7.30 (or 7.0 + 0.3 or 4.3 + 3.0 or whatever). To sum up: Do not rely on string comparison by using strings.

Comment: i store them as double using NSNumber, i get it, 7.30==7.3, but for core data they are different.

Comment: Without a formatter 7.30 for a floating point number wouldn't been reported. Somewhere you use a string. Please add your model, the saving code and the predicate generation to your Q.

Answer (score 1):

```
// remove the zeros from values (if you have them as floats)
NSString *valueFromTheDataBase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", 34.123450];
NSString *yourValue  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", 34.12345];

if([yourValue isEqualToString:valueFromDataBase]) {
// they are equal
}
```

OR Make Them floats and compare them

```
// make them floats and compare them
CGFloat floatFromDB = [valueFromDB floatValue];
CGFloat yourFloat  = [yourString floatValue];
if((floatFromDB - yourFloat) == 0) {
// they are equal
}
```

UPDATED as @Amin Negm  says

Comment: %g change for example 34.787670 to 34.7877 and that's not what i need.

Comment: also, there is no answer from core data if it won't match the result from quad tree (34.787670) so i cannot know if they are equal or not.

Comment: @IdanMoshe, 34.7877 and 34.7887 are really different