# NSFetchedResultsController sort negative string values

Tags: ios, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have `NSFetchedResultsController` which returns objects with `index` attribute, `index` attribute is a `NSString` and for example I have these values for `index` attribute: -1, -3, 1, 0, -2, 3

I need to define NSSortDescriptor which will sort these objects like this based on `index` attribute value:
-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3

Sort descriptor that I have now which doesn't sort the negative values correctly.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ObjectIndex ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

Comment: is your question only related to sorting numbers? It might be better to change the title and remove nsfetchedresultsController. Have you tried : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510167/sorting-negative-and-positive-numbers-in-objective-c ? If it still does not work, please but the result you get, and the entire code for sorting your array.

Comment: it is related to sorting numbers saved as a string property when object is fetched with NSFetchedResultsController. There is a difference with sorting array and sorting while executing sql request. As far as I know there is no possible solution to the question I asked, but maybe someone knows a trick.
The code I provided is enough for someone who is familiar with the matter.

Comment: please don't answer like that. I came to provide some help. Many issues can be solved differently than what the OP thought, such as sorting the array after the fetch. If it is not what you are looking for, then just say it, without bitterness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11) the SQLite backing store for CoreData supports only a handful of sort selectors:

> ... The SQL store, on the other hand, compiles the predicate and sort descriptors to SQL and evaluates the result in the database itself. This is done primarily for performance, but it means that evaluation happens in a non-Cocoa environment, and so sort descriptors (or predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot work. The supported sort selectors are **compare:** and **caseInsensitiveCompare:**, **localizedCompare:**, **localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:**, and **localizedStandardCompare:** (the latter is Finder-like sorting, and what most people should use most of the time).

(my highlighting).  None of these achieves what you want.  As you have found, the last of them comes closest: it sorts negative numbers before positive, and does attempt numerical ordering (so "23" is sorted before "220" - a text ordering would put them the other way round).  But (bizarrely) negative numbers are sorted in order of their absolute value - so "-1" comes before "-2" etc.  Sure enough, Finder sorts negative numbers in the same way.

So I think your best bet is to redesign your database to make this field a numeric type, so that you can use a sensible sort order.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely need to change something, or get rid of the NSFetchedController.