# unable to sort Array in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, dictionary

I have one `NSMutableArray` name is xyz  and each element of `array` contain individual `Dictionary`. i want to sort this main `Dictionary` for example structure :

```
 $0 = 0x0963e730 <__NSArrayM 0x963e730>(
{
    accuracy = 0;
    context = 0;
    dateupload = 1382375073;
    description =     {
        "_content" = "";
    };
    farm = 4;
    id = 10406310594;
    isfamily = 0;
    isfriend = 0;
    ispublic = 1;
    latitude = 0;
    longitude = 0;
    owner = "35744@N03";
    ownername = abc;
    secret = f9fd3;
    server = 3830;
    tags = "";
    title = 17740013;
},
{
    accuracy = 0;
    context = 0;
    dateupload = 1382375072;
    description =     {
        "_content" = "";
    };
    farm = 8;
    id = 10406317735;
    isfamily = 0;
    isfriend = 0;
    ispublic = 1;
    latitude = 0;
    longitude = 0;
    owner = "35944@N03";
    ownername = abc;
    secret = 9665d3ec;
    server = 74;
    tags = "vision:food=0635";
    title = 01200033;
},
```

i want to sort this array by title;

i use LinqToObjectiveC-master library but enable to sort.

Help for this solution, simple solution highly appreciated.

Comment: the structure of your data is invalid. you can't have an array inide a dictionary without key.

Comment: @vikingosegundo please check my question i have modified.

Comment: So that is no dictionary at all.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Please check question again i modified. give me answer thanks

Comment: *"give me answer"* don't you think that this isn't a bit too demanding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to sort an NSArray of NSDictionary objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects)

Comment: @vikingosegundo okes i care next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
NSDictionary *person1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"d",@"name",@"xyz",@"add",nil];
NSDictionary *person2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"e",@"name",@"pqr",@"add",nil];
NSDictionary *person3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"a",@"name",@"stu",@"add",nil];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:person1,person2,person3,nil];

NSSortDescriptor *name = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[arr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:name]];

// before sort
NSLog(@"Before %@",arr);
[arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *item1, NSDictionary *item2) {
    NSString *first = [item1 objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *second = [item2 objectForKey:@"name"];
    return [first compare:second options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];
// After sort
NSLog(@"After %@",arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a key/value collection you can't sort a dictionary, but you can sort the array of values while reading like this:

```
NSArray *dictionaryValues = [flickr allValues];
```

and then sort using a sortDescriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *flickrSortedValues = [dictionaryValues sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```