# Objective-C - tableView, sort JSON array in descending order

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, sorting

This is the JSON, it shows by descending order, id_no

> ```
>  {"users":[
> {"id_no":"501",
>  "type":"User",
>    "country":"United Kingdom",
>    "city":"London"
>  }    
>  {"id_no":"500",
>  "type":"Admin",
>    "country":"United States",
>    "city":"San Fransisco"}
>  ]
> ```

This is my code :

> ```
>  - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
> [super viewDidLoad];
> NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/sohw.php"];
> NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
> NSError *error = nil;
> NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
> self.reports = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"users"];
> }
> ```

What I want to do is to sort `users` in descending order when displayed on the tableView as per as the JSON file.

Any hints on how I can do it ?

Comment: Side note - DO NOT do a synchronous Internet call on the main thread like you are doing in your `viewDidLoad` method. It will hang the user interface and give a bad user experience.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects ?

Comment: @rmaddy it is working fine without any single problem, anyway can you propose any better solution ?

Comment: Do async/GDC. Well, it's blocking your UI for now.

Comment: It won't work fine for some user on a slow cellular connection or when your server is overloaded. Always load data from the Internet on a background thread. Always.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array to be sorted, the best thing would be to look at the NSArray documentation, do a search for the word "sort" and pick a method there that sorts the array. sortedArrayUsingComparator: is my personal favourite.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the key path of the field you want to sort by:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/sohw.php"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id_no" ascending:NO];
    self.reports = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"users"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
}
```

Comment: I've added this answer here in case the [other duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227315/ios-tableview-sort-json-array-in-descending-order/) gets deleted..!