# iOS - tableView, sort JSON array in descending order

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, sorting

This is the JSON, it shows by descending order, id_no

> ```
>  {"users":[
> {"id_no":"501",
>  "type":"User",
>    "country":"United Kingdom",
>    "city":"London"
>  }    
>  {"id_no":"500",
>  "type":"Admin",
>    "country":"United States",
>    "city":"San Fransisco"}
>  ]
> ```

This is my code :

> ```
>  - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
> [super viewDidLoad];
> NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/sohw.php"];
> NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
> NSError *error = nil;
> NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
> self.reports = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"users"];
> }
> ```

What I want to do is to sort `users` in descending order when displayed on the tableView as per as the JSON file.

I have already got answers such as :
[Best way to sort an NSArray of NSDictionary objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects)

or :

> ```
>   NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"interest"  ascending:YES];
>    stories=[stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
>    recent = [stories copy];
> ```

but when I tried to implement it, it does not worked for me according to my current structure of code.

Can you please guide me on how I can solve it, according to the code I provided ?

Comment: Descending order by which field in `users`?

Comment: Why did you post another question? Why didn't you update your previous question with additional details?

Comment: @user3405229 you also don't want to be doing a network call in `viewDidLoad`!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C - tableView, sort JSON array in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225999/objective-c-tableview-sort-json-array-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the key path of the field you want to sort by:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/sohw.php"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id_no" ascending:NO];
    self.reports = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"users"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `id_no` as `key` which is in `dictionary` to `sort` here

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id_no"  ascending:NO];
NSArray *users=[self.reports sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

self.reports = [users mutableCopy];
```

`Mistake` you done is `used` `interest` which is `not key` of `dictionary`

**EDIT** : for `descending order` set `ascending:NO`