# Sort UITableView descending order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting

```
- (NSArray *)combinedStrings {
return [[self.numberOfUsers arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.numberOfModerators]    arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.numberOfAdmins];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  NSDictionary *jsonForJam = [self.combinedStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
  }
```

I would like to sort the result displayed in the tableView in descending order, how can I do such thing ?

I've already tried to use that but it was not helpful : [Best way to sort an NSArray of NSDictionary objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects)

A solution based on the sample code I provided will be very helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with the answers to the previous two questions you've already asked on this subject?

Comment: @rmaddy That worked for me, but I am stuck also in this part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to sort an NSArray of NSDictionary objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects)

Comment: What do you mean "this is a tableview" ?. You are not trying to sort a UITableView, you are trying to sort a NSArray. The duplicate David pointed out to you do the same thing : sorting an NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for sorting array of strings.

```
self.combinedStrings = [[[self.combinedStrings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

or

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
self.combinedStrings = [self.combinedStrings sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: It does not works for me, maybe I did not implemented it in the correct way. Can you please a bit precise. A sample code based on my own code above will be very helpful.

Comment: I guess the 'problem' is that combindedStrings isn't a property, so the code won't compile for him/her. The OP should probably read up on basic (Objective-C) programming.

Answer (score 0):

A) you can implement your own custom sorting method (that still ends up using iOS sorting methods in the end) because the NSDictionary complicates matters.

or

B) create an object (its purpose is to hold all the info in the dictionaries) then store the custom objects in the array, then sort it like this or in any matter you wish:

```
self.combinedStrings = [self.combinedStrings sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
                    {
                        Client *client1 = (Client*)obj1;
                        Client *client2 = (Client*)obj2;
                        if([client1.firstName isEqualToString:client2.firstName])
                        return [client1.lastName compare:client2.lastName];
                        else
                        return [client1.firstName compare:client2.firstName];
                    }];
```

Here "Client" would be the custom object and the data is stored in properties for easy access.

Hope this helps