# Sorting array of wrapper objects in iOS using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to sort an array of UserWrapper objects. The wrapper object contains the object User, and the User object contains the property UserName (that I want to sort by).

It us easy enough to sort an array of Users ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393386/best-way-to-sort-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects)), but the added layer of UserWrapper complicates things for me. Help please!

Here is my code, which worked for a simple User array:

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"UserName"
                                                               ascending:YES
                                                                selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] ; 

NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor];
NSMutableArray *contactsStartingWithKey = [nameIndexesDictionary objectForKey:aKey];
[contactsStartingWithKey sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors]; // Exception thrown here because UserName is not a property of UserWrapper, but of UserWrapper.User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *key* argument of the sort descriptor can also by a *key path*, in your case:

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"User.UserName"
                            ascending:YES
                             selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the API and documentation of `NSSortDescriptor` are a bit inconsistent, the "key" parameter is actually a key path. So, you can just specify `@"User.UserName"` as the key and your code should work.